# gulp jquery-validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, gulp

I'm suddenly getting an error in my gulp build related to jquery validation. As far as I know nothing has changed that would cause this. One of my other coworkers is getting it as well, but a third is not. We've compared and can't find any differences and we're all working from the same github repo with the same package.json and gulp file.

The error is :
`Cannot find module 'jquery' from '/Users/myuser/Documents/workspaces/mavensmate/proj1/node_modules/jquery-validation/dist'`

There is no jquery file in that directory, but my coworker that isn't getting the error doesn't have a jquery file there either.

I've tried:

- npm install
- restarting gulp server
- restarting computer
- making sure no other servers are running
- deleting all modules and re-running npm install
- testing in a branch (diff directory) of the repo (works there)

Any suggestions?

Full error dump:

```
stream: 
   Labeled {
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        highWaterMark: 16,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: [Object],
        pipesCount: 1,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        resumeScheduled: false },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        data: [Function: ondata],
        _mutate: [Object] },
     _eventsCount: 4,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        highWaterMark: 16,
        objectMode: true,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [],
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _options: { objectMode: true },
     _wrapOptions: { objectMode: true },
     _streams: [ [Object] ],
     length: 1,
     label: 'deps' } }
```

Comment: It says `module` jquery. Check if your co-workers who don't get the error have that module installed as a global npm package.

Comment: @DrinkBird so i just did a `npm install jquery` and that seems to have resolved it, still not sure why it needed this in this project and not the sandbox version

Comment: Nice. It's definitely referenced somewhere, maybe as a dependency of another package. The usual problem is that global packages are not tracked through a project.json file, therefore their versions can vary between different machines. Even worse, different versions of the same package may have different dependencies. In general, make sure to include all necessary packages in your project file.

Comment: @DrinkBird thanks, if you post that as an answer ill accept

Comment: Thanks mate, best of luck with your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says `module jquery`. Check if your co-workers who don't get the error have that module installed as a global npm package.

It's definitely referenced somewhere, maybe as a dependency of another package. The usual problem is that global packages are not tracked through a `project.json` file, therefore their versions can vary between different machines. Even worse, different versions of the same package may have different dependencies.

In general, make sure to include all necessary packages in your project file.